# flutter firebase auth current user email for appbar title

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

User already login to the app by using firebase email login.
How to make the appbar title to be the current user email?

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final  Future<String> userEmail = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) => user.email);
  var e = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text('userEmail'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: _signOut,
                child: new Text('logout', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white))
            ),

          ],
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text(
            e,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setState()` after you have the new user.

In your code, you create the `Future<String> email` but aren't able to capitalize on the eventual `user.email` evaluation.

I recommend creating a non-final variable to hold your `FirebaseUser` and then trigger the request for this in the `State`'s `initState()` method.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser; // not final
```

The goal is to eventually be able to call `setState()` **after** receiving the FirebaseUser (since that's asynchronous).

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
   setState(() { // call setState to rebuild the view
     this.currentUser = user;
   });
});
```

An important thing to note is that you have to build your UI for all the possible states of `currentUser` which are:

- `null` (before the call completes)
- and, well, not null.

So you need to make sure you handle the `null` case with logic similar to:

```
String _email() {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      return currentUser.email;
    } else {
      return "no current user";
    }
}
```

Below is an example adapted from your code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  FirebaseUser currentUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCurrentUser();
  }

  void _loadCurrentUser() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
      setState(() { // call setState to rebuild the view
        this.currentUser = user;
      });
    });
  }

  String _email() {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      return currentUser.email;
    } else {
      return "no current user";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text('userEmail'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: _signOut,
                child: new Text('logout',
                    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white))),
          ],
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text(
            _email(),
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, it is working well. I would like to ask you one more question. When should i use the async? I thought I should use async function in my case, but it is not.

Comment: If you want (I would) you can mark `_loadCurrentUser()async{ ` with the async keyword. Then you can remove the `.then()` call and instead use an `await` in front.